# How to get SID in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, payment, payment-methods, session

I'm trying to add online payment in my magento store and the bank that I work with suggest for making tests that I send to them some variables for testing the security (between them the SID).

**So my question is how to get SID in magento.**

Answer (score 6):

You can get the session ID with the below code:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$SID = $session->getEncryptedSessionId(); //current session id
```

You can easily get session-id from the core/session model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just I need to know where exactly to put code to make it work and display $SID

Comment: you can see this code anywhere at frontend.As for payment gateway,you need to send data to it redirect url.

Comment: I create a file in www folder and place this code but it didn't show nothing after the line Mage::getSingleton('core/session')

Comment: have you knowledge about magento basic structure ?

Comment: No Not too much

Comment: which payment gateway, you have using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23563/discussion-between-fares-omrani-and-amit-bera).

Comment: TIll now I'm using no one I just gonna made a static form containing some variables (Shipping Reference, SID, Bank ID ...) to send it to the bank who gonna make the tests so I need to know the SID